# Databinding doesnt display anything

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to print out observable collection into the listview.
It is for custom navigation. It should output 2 buttons with icon and one button should have active element.

For some reason I am not able to see anything. It works without problem when I use same code in Main.xaml/Main.xaml.cs. Maybe there is limitation on Application class that prevents databinding?

App.Xaml

```
                        <!--test-->
                        <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding NavigationItemss}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <StackLayout>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Icon}"></Label>
                                            <Label Text="Testing"></Label>
                                        </StackLayout>

                                    </ViewCell>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                        <!--test-->
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    //TODO: Replace with *.azurewebsites.net url after deploying backend to Azure
    public static string AzureBackendUrl = "http://localhost:5000";
    public static bool UseMockDataStore = true;
    Navigation AppNavigation = new Navigation();
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (UseMockDataStore)
            DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
        else
            DependencyService.Register<AzureDataStore>();
        this.BindingContext = AppNavigation;
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Main());


    }
```

Navigation.cs

```
using HOT_App.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HOT_App.ViewModels
{
    class Navigation
    {
        //public List<NavigationItem> NavigationItems;
        public ObservableCollection<NavigationItem> NavigationItemss { get; set; }

        public Navigation()
        { 
            NavigationItemss = new ObservableCollection<NavigationItem>();
            //NavigationItems = new List<NavigationItem>();
            NavigationItem Home = new NavigationItem("Home","NavigationHome.png",true);
            NavigationItem Trends = new NavigationItem("Trends","NavigationTrend.png",false);
            NavigationItemss.Add(Home);
            NavigationItemss.Add(Trends);
            //NavigationItems.Add(Home);
            //NavigationItems.Add(Trends);
        }


        public void ShowActiveNavigation()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Join<NavigationItem>("\n", NavigationItemss));
        }

        public void SetActiveNavigation(string activeNavigationName)
        {
            ChangeActiveValue(activeNavigationName);
            switch (activeNavigationName)
            {
                case "Home":
                    //activeNavigation = new NavigationItem("Home");
                    Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Main(), false);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Home");
                    break;
                case "Trends":
                    //activeNavigation = new NavigationItem("Trends");
                    Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Trends(), false);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Trends");
                    break;
                default:
                    //activeNavigation = new NavigationItem("Home");
                    Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Main(), false);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Home");
                    break;

            }

        }
        public void ChangeActiveValue(string activeNavigationName)
        {
            foreach(NavigationItem navigationItem in NavigationItemss)
            {

                if (navigationItem.NavigationItemName == activeNavigationName)
                {
                    navigationItem.Active = true;
                }
                else { navigationItem.Active = false; }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: First, your binding expression has an extra 's' in it `"{Binding NavigationItemss}"`.  Further, why is your ListView defined in App.xaml and not in MainPage?  App is for application level code, not page-specific views.

Comment: Hi @Jason Extra "s" is not a misstake. Its the name of the observable.Its application level code. App.xaml is just layout(Basic informations like battery status, Navigation)

Comment: is this ListView supposed to appear on MainPage?   If so, then please post that code.

Comment: No @Jason its not, Its navigation. Its not content. App.xaml is just layout which has buttons. This buttons should be generated using Navigation.cs.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense.  If you want to have a flyout nav menu typically you would use a MasterDetail page.  I'm not sure how/where you expect this nav menu to display?

Comment: @Jason I need custom menu. Thats why I created custom Navigation. Only thing that does not work is displaying it in listview.

Comment: @trixo could you please share the code you have so far on GitHub or something? Jason brought up some really good points

Comment: @Saamer sorry, Cant do that. But thanks for help

Comment: i think you could use MasterDetails page ,and create navigable pages on the menu page.Normally we don't create pages in App.xaml

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT my application is completely different from the rest. I dont need back buttons or anything like that. IT would take me ages to adjust master detail page to my needs. All I need is to have 2 buttons which changes what pages is displayed. Question has been updated with new info.

Comment: i think MasterDetailPage is the the fastest way to solve your problem, you just need to configure  Master and Detail page,Master page is your navigation page which you use ListView,and the detail page is your Main and Home pages

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Yes, Could you please write answer to the question ? So I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataBinding works inside the controlTemplate as well. You can find more info about it here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/template-binding

Answer (score 2):

Normally we don't create pages in  `App.xaml`

i think **MasterDetailPage** is the the fastest way to solve your problem, you just need to configure **Master** and **Detail** page,Master page here is your navigation page which you use ListView,and the detail page is your Main and Home pages.

you could refer to the [MasterDetails Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page)

ps: you could also use [**Shell**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/create) if your Xamarin.Forms  is 4.0 and above